# How to find why Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows-server

I am not very familier with Windows servers and I was asked to put asp.net app and new windows server. As the app owner could not provide any documentation, I manage to set it up where I am stack at Exception error.
The app page is just white screen and I get this error:

```
w3wp.exe Error: 0 :  <19.09.2023 06:26:52> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Core.Web.Controls.SmartView.SaveChildViewState()
   at Core.Web.Controls.SmartView.SaveViewState()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive(ViewStateMode inheritedMode)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive(ViewStateMode inheritedMode)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive(ViewStateMode inheritedMode)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive(ViewStateMode inheritedMode)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive(ViewStateMode inheritedMode)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive(ViewStateMode inheritedMode)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.SaveViewStateRecursive(ViewStateMode inheritedMode)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.SaveAllState()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I understand that I need to check `InnerException` but how to access it, if I don't know nothing about this app's code.

Comment: That looks like a bug in `Core.Web.Controls.SmartView` - which I assume is a third-party control you're using?

Comment: I am not sure, as I mentioned this code came without any documentation and I am not good at C# and .net apps.  This line I see in Web.conf file. 
`<add tagPrefix="core" namespace="Core.Web.Controls" assembly="Core" />`